# When I extends the Interface in React class component and write the enzyme test getting an error that all prop and state has to passed to enzyme code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enzyme

I am new for react and as per requirement of my personal project I am have the following React class component. I am writing a enzyme Test script for the following code.
I am getting an error:

```
/***************************************React Class Component:
export class testDataClass{

    id: '',
    label:'',
    name:'',
    message:''
};
export interface ITestData {
    testNume: number;
    testType:  string;
    testId: string;
    isTestSection: boolean;
};
interface ITestItemProps {
    testData : ITestData;
    testData2: testDataClass;
    width: number;
};


interface ITestItemState {
    isTest: boolean;
    isTest1: string;
    isTest2: boolean;
};



export class TestItem extends React.Component<ITestItemProps, ITestItemState> {
    constructor(props:ITestItemProps){
        super(props);

        .....some code for state
    }

    public render(){

    }
};


/**************************Enzyme Code:
import * as React from 'react';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { configure, mount,shallow  } from 'enzyme';

describe('Test Data Test', () => {
     it('Test Data Test', () => {   
        const result  = mount(<TestItem  {...props}/>); 

    });
};
```

Can someone please help that why I am getting this error ? I can just pass the props but state I cannot pass. Or if someone can provide me a code example , it would really help for me.

Thanks

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I am getting an error for the following code : 
 const result  = mount(<TestItem  {...props}/>); 
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<ITestItemProps>': ......., and 2 more.